# How do I get a CSS selector to target only the header elements within article elements?

Tags: css, html, header, element, article

I am not familiar with CSS and I need to target only the header elements within article elements. I know some have `#`, `.` or `,`.

```
article header
article, header
article.header
article#header
```

and I think others as well.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 7):

OK, you asked for 4 selectors, let's go.

> article header

Space is children selector, it means `header` element in `article`, like

```
<article>
    <header></header>
</article>
```

`Header` element which isn't in `article` won't be styled.

> article, header

It styles both (all) elements which are separated by comma, it's a list of elements. It doesn't matter if they are parent&child, siblings, or nothing.

```
<header>...</header>
<article>...</article>
<header><article></article></header>
```

> article.header
>   dot is `class`, now you're looking for `article` with `class="header"`

```
<article class="header">...</article>
```

Element can have more classes, not just this one.

```
<article class="header second">...</article>
```

> article#header

The same as above, just `ID` instead of class.

```
<article id="header">...</article>
```

Since `id` is unique identifier and in your site can't be another one with the same ID, you can write it shortly as

```
#header
```

The difference between `#header` and `article#header` is, that `#header` styles all elements with this ID, not just `article`s. Eg. `<div id="header">` will be styled too.

Answer (score 6):

`article header` means `header` elements inside `article` elements. This is what you want.

`article, header` means all `article` elements and all `header` elements.

`article.header` means `article` elements with a `header` class.

`article#header` means `article` element with ID `header`.

Reference here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp